# Inheritance with Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, inheritance, laravel-5

I have a **master_page.blade** with global content for my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    @include('layout.head')
</head>
<body>
    @include('layout.header')


    @yield('master_content')

    @section('footer')
        @include('layout.footer')
    @show

    @include('layout.scripts')

    @yield('custom_scripts')

</body>
</html>
```

After, I have a layout in Bootstrap with 2-6 columns, this blade inherit of the master_blade, his name is **2_10_columns.blade**:

```
@extends('layout.master_page')

@section('master_content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="main-content">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            @section('content1')
            @show
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-10">     
            @section('content2')
            @show

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@stop
```

Ok, this looks good but, finally I need fill the 2_10_columns.blade with some content, for example I tried this with mi **contact.blade.php**:

```
@extends('layout.2_10_columns')

@section('content1')
    <p>Column 2 left content of my section...</p>
@stop

@section('content2')
    <p>Column 10 right content of my section ...</p>
    ...some forms here
@stop
```

Definitely this does not work...

**How could I do this with Laravel? Look at this infographic:**
[image]

Comment: Of those three views, which one are you trying to return from the controller?

Comment: Doesn't `2_10_columns.blade` need to have `@yield('content1')` instead of `@section('content1')` since you're extending that blade template?

Comment: How about creating 2 master pages one just with container and one with col2+col10?

Comment: @JeffLambert my controller is getContact() and return the view contact.blade

Comment: @camelCase with yield It does not work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its working like this(simplified for example):

master layout:

```
<html>
<body>
 <div class="container">
   @yield('master_content')
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

2 cols layout:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('master_content')
 <div class="co-l2">
   <p>index</p>
   @yield('sidebar')
 </div>
 <div class="col-10">
   @yield('content')
 </div>
@endsection
```

contact view:

```
@extends('layouts.2cols')

@section('sidebar')
  <p>delete</p>
@endsection

@section('content')
   <h1> person name </h1>
   <p>about the person</p>
@endsection
```